# Where can I find the refind.conf configuration file?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, macbook-pro, refind

I'm in the process of installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS on macbook pro 13inch retina display with the end goal of having a dual boot setup with OS X. I'm using reFind as my boot manager, and since I have disk encryption enabled on my OS X partition, I can't install reFind on my mac os x partition. To work around this I created a separate 1GB partition just for the reFind boot manager and installed refind on it using install.sh with the --ownhfs and --alldrivers options. Currently my diskutil list output looks like this :

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ yatin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1 -- ESP
   2:                  Apple_HFS REFIND_BOOTMGR          864.0 MB   disk0s2 -- custom HFS refind partition
   3:                  Apple_HFS OS X                    82.9 GB    disk0s3 -- OS X
   4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4 
   5: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               83.5 GB    disk0s5 -- ubuntu
   6:                 Linux Swap                         14.5 GB    disk0s6 
   7: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               68.4 GB    disk0s7 -- shared volume
```

Now when I boot up my mac, I see refind's boot selector which displays three entries, one for ubuntu, one for my mac and a third for grub. I would like to remove the grub refind entry since it serves no purpose given that refind is booting my ubuntu image directly, but I'm unable to find the refind.conf file. I don't see the refind.conf under the usual location on the REFIND_BOOTMGR volume ie /EFI/refind/refind.conf. Where should it be located ?

Comment: Try to find it using command `locate refind.conf`

Comment: @girardengo - I tried using locate from the mac but it wasn't able to find any refind.conf files on the 1GB bootmgr partition.

Answer (score 14):

Although refind is good, there seems to be an awful lot missing from the instructions page, it could do with being proofread by someone other than the author so that all the dozens of "what does that mean?" or "where's that located?" questions can be answered right at the start. What's obvious to someone writing the program may not be so obvious to those trying to use it.

Anyway, to find its proper location I managed to find some clues in the uninstall portion of the instructions. These point back to the manual installation guide for instructions on mounting the unmounted EFI partition, et voila!

**diskutil list** to get a list of partitions, in my case EFI is disk0s1.

**mkdir /Volumes/esp** to create somewhere to mount the volume to.

**sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/esp** to mount the volume.

Now look in **/Volumes/esp/EFI/refind** to find your refind.conf file. Alternatively Finder will now have mounted a disk called EFI in your Devices list on the left-hand-side, so you can click on that and browse to **EFI/refind**.

Googling for the answer found this page so hopefully this little snippet of info will be useful for others trying to track it down.

Comment: ... It's the first FAT partition on the disk. I was looking for at the HFS+ one. So weird. Somehow, I have three 210mb EFI partitions... 2 in FAT and one in HFS+

Answer (score 1):

If you installed with the `--ownhfs` option, then `refind.conf` will be in the `System/Library/CoreServices` directory on the partition you specified with `--ownhfs`.

Note that rEFInd auto-detects boot loaders, so if you really want to never use GRUB again, another option is to delete the `grubx64.efi` file from wherever it was installed (probably your ESP).

Answer (score 1):

If installed via OSX: 
`sudo mountesp`

The terminal will then tell you where to look, typically /Volumes/ESP
From there you can find `refind.conf` at:

`/Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind/refind.conf`

From the [rEFInd author](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html):

> Since 0.9.3, rEFInd has provided a script called mountesp, which
>   locates and mounts the ESP. Open a Terminal and type sudo mountesp to
>   mount the ESP. The program should tell you where it's mounted the ESP.
>   It will remain mounted until you manually unmount it or until you
>   reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run:

```
mkdir /Volumes/esp
```

Instead use:

```
diskutil mount /dev/disk0s1
```

Go to finder and you will see it in: `EFI>EFI>refind>refind.conf`

PS: make sure to edit it with sudo.