# MacBook Pro 7,1 + Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + nVidia drivers

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, macbook-pro, refind

After following the guide I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating/613573#613573) I found that although my hardware is the same as its author I could not reproduce the same results. After creating the GRUB script to register the PCI registers during boot, making the file executable, and updating the GRUB config files (i.e., after following **Step 3**) I enter:

`sudo setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b`

According to step 4 it outputs `00` instead of the expected `08`

However, when I enter

`sudo setpci -s "04:00.0" 04.b`

it returns the expected value of `07` as is found in the guide.

What else should I do to ensure I can utilize the nVidia drivers on my setup?

I don't completely understand the guide, but have the same hardware and followed the same instructions.

I have a dual-boot MacBook Pro (7,1) with OS X and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

rEFInd (version 0.10.3-1) is my boot loader.

==**EDIT**==

After inputing

```
dmesg | grep -i efi
```

I get the following:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: \boot\vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic.efi.signed ro root=UUID=d5117e29-6aa7-46cb-ab22-616c19309a3c initrd=boot\initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v1.10 by Apple
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI=0xbf96a000  ACPI 2.0=0xbf96a014  SMBIOS=0xbf71a000 
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: \boot\vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic.efi.signed ro root=UUID=d5117e29-6aa7-46cb-ab22-616c19309a3c initrd=boot\initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
[    0.953332] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.953363] efifb: framebuffer at 0xc0010000, mapped to 0xffffc90002800000, using 6400k, total 6400k
[    0.953370] efifb: mode is 1280x800x32, linelength=8192, pages=1
[    0.953374] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.953378] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.961402] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    2.227701] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    2.853971] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(IGPU) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    2.952253] fb: switching to nouveaufb from EFI VGA
```

These are more of my outputs when following said guide.

**2. Find the right PCI-E bus identifiers**

`sudo lshw -businfo -class bridge -class display`

> ```
> Bus info          Device      Class          Description
> ========================================================
> pci@0000:00:00.0              bridge         MCP89 HOST Bridge
> pci@0000:00:03.0              bridge         MCP89 LPC Bridge
> pci@0000:00:0e.0              bridge         NVIDIA Corporation
> pci@0000:00:15.0              bridge         NVIDIA Corporation
> pci@0000:00:16.0              bridge         NVIDIA Corporation
> pci@0000:00:17.0              bridge         MCP89 PCI Express Bridge
> pci@0000:04:00.0              display        MCP89 [GeForce 320M]
> ```

**3. Create a GRUB script for setting the PCI-E registers during boot**

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
```

Then enter the following:

```
cat << EOF
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "04:00.0" 04.b=7
EOF
```

Ctrl + X

Y for Yes to save config file.

Then run

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
sudo update-grub
```

Both of those commands execute fine.

**4. Reboot and check**

Upon rebooting I run:

```
sudo setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b
```

And get `00` instead of the expected `08`.

I also run:

```
sudo setpci -s "04:00.0" 04.b
```

which returns the expected `07`, just like the guide.

Let me know if I can provide more details to help me solve this issue.

**==UPDATE==**

I had previously (i.e., before attempting to follow the guide) deleted the "ubuntu" folder (and therefore it's corresponding grub settings) that is installed on the EFI partition while installing Ubuntu in order to get rEFInd to show up on start-up.  I had thought that the two were competing since back then I would start the MacBook and it would automatically boot into Ubuntu without showing the rEFInd menu.

After uninstalling rEFInd, reinstalling Ubuntu, and setting the Grub menu as shown [here](http://computechtips.com/960/install-linuxmint-macbook) I ran the steps in the Nvidia Driver guide. I got the correct output this time.

[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqPIb.png)

However, now when selecting the "NVIDIA legacy binary driver version 304.131 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)" from the GUI 'Additional Drivers' menu and applying changes it doesn't switch the selection out of the Nouveau setting.

Thinking it was a GUI glitch, I wait a while then rebooted anyway, but no dice -- the Nouveau driver is still used after start-up.

I'm wanting to be cautious in proceeding so what command lines should I input from here?

(Note: An additional frustration is that after this reinstallation process my WiFi is now not working properly despite proper drivers being used.  This was not an issue before, but I'll deal with that after I can resolve the Nvidia drivers. Perhaps the wifi woes for 16.04 and Broadcom 432b are related to something with the boot loaders as well?)

Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: Testing if it works would be a good idea. Also, I'd read it again, or ask about stuff you don't understand.

Comment: @mikewhatever 

It doesn't work.  The screen goes black upon booting and TTY is inaccessible.  Only rebooting in single-user mode via rEFInd and pressing "Enter" to enter maintenance will provide me with a command line.  From there I `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` and then `sudo reboot`.  After rebooting, it defaults back to the nouveau driver which allows me to access the system again.

What I don't understand is:

1) Why do I get `00` as output rather than `08`?
2) What role dose grub play if I am using rEFInd?
3) What commands would help me diagnose / resolve this issue?

Comment: 1) Hard to tell. You need to post the outputs from 2 and 3, or double check you've done everything right. 2) The guide is based on grub, so if you know how to pull the same trick with other boot loaders, let us know. 3)If the guide doesn't work, you'd need to do some research.

Comment: @mikewhatever Added more info on the edit of the OP.   Also, as far as I know rEFInd can boot grub EFI, but I'll have to do some digging to see if that process is the culprit on my setup.

Comment: @mikewhatever Updated OP. I seem to have fixed the issue with getting different results upon checking the grub scripts, but am wanting some guidance for changing from the nouveau driver to the nvidia one.

Comment: I am not sure commands will help, but you could try `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. For more info, see `ubutnu-drivers --help.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling rEFInd, reinstalling Ubuntu so that the "ubuntu" folder appears in the EFI partition (e.g., opening 'Terminal' on OS X, running `sudo mountesp` and then viewing the EFI partition in Finder), setting the Grub menu (as detailed [here](http://computechtips.com/960/install-linuxmint-macbook)) and following the [instructions in the original guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating/613573#613573) I was able to get the expected outputs of `08` and `07` before attempting to install the proprietary nVidia drivers.

When first attempting to install the proprietary nVidia drivers via the "Additional Software" GUI they would not install and upon reboot the open source Nouveau driver was being used.

However, when on the login page I accessed TTY1 (i.e., `FN + Control + alt + F1`), logged in, ran `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, and rebooted.  Once I logged back into Ubuntu, I opened "Terminal" and ran `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`, then `sudo apt-get update`, followed by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and then rebooted.

This resulted in a successful start-up of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro (7,1) in a dual-boot configuration (OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan) utilizing Grub as my boot loader.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you to the guides linked herein and @mikewhatever for helping me address this issue.  Hopefully this will help others who may encounter similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem when setpci doesn't change the value of PCI-E bridge.

If you are unable to set the value of PCI-E brigde register using setpci command in order to get nVidia GeForce drivers working on your Apple MacBook machine try these steps:

### 1. Find your PCI-E bus identifiers

```
lshw -businfo -class bridge -class display

[root@kernelLinux]# lshw -businfo -class bridge -class display
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
pci@0000:00:00.0              bridge         MCP89 HOST Bridge
pci@0000:00:03.0              bridge         MCP89 LPC Bridge
pci@0000:00:15.0              bridge         NVIDIA Corporation
pci@0000:00:17.0              bridge         MCP89 PCI Express Bridge
pci@0000:02:00.0              display        MCP89 [GeForce 320M]
```

You will need the ID's of **PCI Express Bridge** and your **display** in format XX:XX.X

Your ID's can be different.

In this example our ID's are **00:17.0** for PCI-E brige and **02:00.0** for display [GPU].

### 2. Create a GRUB script

Our script will be slightly different than in mentioned post above.

I have noticed of two things. Grub2 installed using distro (mine is Centos) installation process doesn't contain **setpci** grub module. It's the reason why grub do not change registers while boot.
Then It is necessary to load setpci module into grub before we run commands to change registers.

Download grub2-efi-modules

Ubuntu Linux

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-bin
```

Fedora Linux

```
sudo dnf install grub2-efi-modules
```

CentOS Linux

```
sudo yum install grub2-efi-modules
```

Modules will be installed in /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/
but the setpci module files needs to be present in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/x86_64-efi/

Create x86_64-efi folder.

Ubuntu folder in /boot/EFI/ can be different on your machine depends how you named it in OS installation process, do not paste it. Replace it with correct path.

```
sudo mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/x86_64-efi
```

Copy setpci module files into grub2 folder

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/setpci.* /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/x86_64-efi
```

Create the 01_enable_vga.conf file.

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
```

The file should contain these lines of code:

Do not forget replace 00:17.0 for PCI-bridge and 02:00.0 for display [GPU] with your values.

```
cat << EOF
insmod setpci
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7
EOF
```

Then repair permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
```

and update the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg

Ubuntu Linux

```
sudo update-grub
```

Do this command only on other distributions (not necessary on Ubuntu after update-grub):

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

### 3. Reboot your system and check registers

Reboot your machine and check if it's working. Replace ID's with yours again. Your terminal should finally show 08 (PCI-E bridge) and 07 (GPU).

```
sudo setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b
08

sudo setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b
07
```

### 4. Install nVidia drivers

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nim4Z.jpg

Comment: The whole process is identical on any distro with grub2 efi bootloader. I only need examine which package in ubuntu repositories contains grub2-efi-modules.

Comment: I updated it.I would like to automatize it and create a script for whole thing in future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the token `spoof_osx_version` in `refind.conf`. From rEFInd documentation http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html:

> On some Macs, this option causes rEFInd to tell the firmware that the
>   specified version of OS X is being launched, even when another OS is
>   selected. The effect is that the firmware may initialize hardware
>   differently, which may have beneficial (or detrimental) results. If
>   your Mac's video output isn't working normally, this option may help.
>   On the other hand, keyboards and mice are known to sometimes stop
>   functioning if this option is used, so you shouldn't use it
>   unnecessarily. This option has no effect on non-Apple hardware. The
>   default is to not use this feature.

I have a Macbook Pro 7,1 with a dual boot of macOS Sierra and Ubuntu 16.04, so I set:

```
spoof_osx_version = 10.12
```

If you wonder on how to edit the `refind.conf` file, please refer to [Where can I find the refind.conf configuration file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468483/where-can-i-find-the-refind-conf-configuration-file).