# setpci doesn't change the register value for the bridge device (NVIDIA driver black screen issue)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I've recently set up my Macbook Air (late 2010) to dual-boot OS 10.10 with Ubuntu 16.04, and of course along the way I've run into the black screen problem when using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. I've just tried Andreas' fix [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264247/proprietary-nvidia-drivers-with-efi-on-mac-to-prevent-overheating). It all seems to go swimmingly, except that when I get to step #4 to reboot and check, I don't get the correct result for the PCI-E register for the bridge device. This is what I get for step #2:

```
Bus info          Device     Class          Description
=======================================================
pci@0000:00:00.0             bridge         MCP89 HOST Bridge
pci@0000:00:03.0             bridge         MCP89 LPC Bridge
pci@0000:00:15.0             bridge         NVIDIA Corporation
pci@0000:00:17.0             bridge         MCP89 PCI Express Bridge
pci@0000:02:00.0             display        MCP89 [GeForce 320M]
```

I've created the grub script */etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf* as described:

```
cat << EOF
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7
EOF
```

...and also changed the permissions and updated grub...

```
~> sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
~> sudo update-grub
```

...but when I reboot the machine and check, the value for the bridge device is incorrect:

```
~> sudo setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b
00
~> sudo setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b
07
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to get this set correctly before I install the NVIDIA drivers? Am I changing the wrong bridge device? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got value 0a for the 00:17.0 register, rather than the desired 08, after booting into X (without using nvidia drivers). Yet, the grub command line showed the correct value of 8 and enabling the NVidia drivers worked. So giving it a try might be worth it even in such cases.

Comment: what was the solution to get 8 and not 0a?

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem when setpci doesn't change the value of PCI-E bridge.

If you are unable to set the value of PCI-E brigde registers using setpci command in order to get nVidia GeForce drivers working on your Apple MacBook machine try these steps:

### 1. Find your PCI-E bus identifiers

```
lshw -businfo -class bridge -class display

[root@kernelLinux]# lshw -businfo -class bridge -class display
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
pci@0000:00:00.0              bridge         MCP89 HOST Bridge
pci@0000:00:03.0              bridge         MCP89 LPC Bridge
pci@0000:00:15.0              bridge         NVIDIA Corporation
pci@0000:00:17.0              bridge         MCP89 PCI Express Bridge
pci@0000:02:00.0              display        MCP89 [GeForce 320M]
```

You will need the ID's of **PCI Express Bridge** and your **display** in format XX:XX.X

Your ID's can be different.

In this example our ID's are **00:17.0** for PCI-E brige and **02:00.0** for display [GPU].

### 2. Create a GRUB script

Our script will be slightly different than in mentioned post above.

I have noticed of two things. Grub2 installed using distro (mine is Centos) installation process doesn't contain **setpci** grub module. It's the reason why grub do not change registers while boot.
Then It is necessary to load setpci module into grub before we run commands to change registers.

Download grub2-efi-modules

Ubuntu Linux

```
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-bin
```

Fedora Linux

```
sudo dnf install grub2-efi-modules
```

CentOS Linux

```
sudo yum install grub2-efi-modules
```

Modules will be installed in /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/
but the setpci module files needs to be present in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/x86_64-efi/

Create x86_64-efi folder.

Ubuntu folder in /boot/EFI/ can be different on your machine depends how you named it in OS installation process, do not paste it. Replace it with correct path.

```
sudo mkdir /boot/EFI/ubuntu/x86_64-efi
```

Copy setpci module files into grub2 folder

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/setpci.* /boot/EFI/ubuntu/x86_64-efi
```

Create the 01_enable_vga.conf file.

The file should contain these lines of code:

Do not forget replace 00:17.0 for PCI-bridge and 02:00.0 for display [GPU] with your values.

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf

cat << EOF
insmod setpci
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7
EOF
```

Then repair permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf
```

and update the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg

Ubuntu Linux

```
sudo update-grub
```

Do this command only on other distributions (not necessary on Ubuntu after update-grub):

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

### 3. Reboot your system and check registers

Reboot your machine and check if it's working. Replace ID's with yours again. Your terminal should finally show 08 (PCI-E bridge) and 07 (GPU).

```
sudo setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b
08

sudo setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b
07
```

### 4. Install nVidia drivers

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nim4Z.jpg

Comment: screenshots up..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got here because of google. It seems both you and I were confused by the file /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf

You want to have the file contain the cat command, you don't want to create it with cat (well, you can create it with nested cat). So try this:

```
sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/grub.d/01_enable_vga.conf" << END
cat << EOF
setpci -s "00:17.0" 3e.b=8
setpci -s "02:00.0" 04.b=7
EOF
END
```

I got the answer here:
[MacBook Pro 7,1 + Ubuntu 16.04 LTS + nVidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772438/macbook-pro-7-1-ubuntu-16-04-lts-nvidia-drivers)